# How do I use regex within a String.split without splitting on international characters?

Tags: regex, string, unicode, elixir

I am working on an elixir problem where I have a phrase:

`phrase = "duck duck goose more_ducks hyphenated-duck überduck"`

I am attempting to split this string into a list of words where underscored words are separate words and hyphenated words are not. The following code works for me:

`String.split(phrase, ~r{([^\w'-]+|_)})`

with exception of the umlaut character, which it splits the word on.
I would like for it not to split on international characters, but can't see to find a way that will work.

I have tried several permutations of `^p{Ll}$/u` with the latest being:

`String.split(~r{[^\w'-]+/^\p{L}/u|_})`

I haven't been able to find out the purpose of the '$' before /u in my readings either, but it shows up in a lot of examples.  I seem to get some sort or error no matter where I place it in the regex section.

Any insight or help would be very appreciated.  I feel I am missing something basic.

Thank you in advance

UPDATE: One of the insights in the comments gave me a solution and explanation to my problem. The "u" is modifying the ~r{} sigil. When I put the "u" in the correct place, it worked fine:

`String.split(~r{([^\w'-]+|_)}u)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Regex.scan/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html?#scan/3) which is more natural here. You need to explicitly set regex to unicode (`u` modifier to `~r//` sigil) and match the sequence of subsequent letters and/or dashes.

```rb
Regex.scan ~r/[\p{L}'’-]+/u, phrase
#⇒ [
#    ["duck"],
#    ["duck"],
#    ["goose"],
#    ["more"],
#    ["ducks"],
#    ["hyphenated-duck"],
#    ["überduck"]
#  ]
```

---

*Sidenote:*

> German character

Umlaut is by no mean “a German character,” it’s so-called [combining diacritical mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks#Character_table) named **diaeresis** that is used in many languages beyond German. See English word **naïve**, or French company **Citroën** for example.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  And I corrected the "german character" comment to be more correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use Regex at all:

```elixir
String.split(phrase, [" ", "_"])
```

Output:

```elixir
["duck", "duck", "goose", "more", "ducks", "hyphenated-duck", "überduck"]
```

Comment: That’s smart but I always opt-in for whitelisting rather than blacklisting (`scan` over `split` in this particular case.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: While Aleksei's answer answers the question asked, my answer provides the best way to achieve the stated result: "split this string into a list of words where underscored words are separate words and hyphenated words are not".

Answer (score -2):

Regular expressions can be somewhat hard to read.  Much easier would be to use the `xr` wrapper for Python's regular expressions.

```
% pip install xr
% python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 21 2020, 10:48:26)
...
>>> from xr import Text
>>> Text(' ').split('a b c')
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

`xr` also provides a bit of syntactic sugar for this use case:

```
WhiteSpace.split('a b c d')
```

Anyhow, you might be interested to know that I just added your duck duck goose example string to `xd`'s unit tests.

```
>>> WhiteSpace.split("duck duck goose more_ducks hyphenated-duck überduck")
['duck', 'duck', 'goose', 'more_ducks', 'hyphenated-duck', 'überduck']
```

Comment: The question is about Elixir, not Python. Also, `more_ducks` is supposed to be split into two words.